# Revert Back DataGridview Column headerText Back to DataSource column Names

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView Control in C# winforms, it has a datatable set as its datasource, after binding datasource, I've changed grid headertext of some columns, now I want to set grid column names back to original datatable column names.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can use gridcolumn.Name property to update my changed gridcolumn.headerText, thanks.